# Updating user data via seed method MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am checking to add a default user to an MVC 5 application. This code works okay, but how do I update this data once it's in the database via the seed method? For example, if I wanted to change the email address? Or add the user to a role? Any help appreciated.

```
if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "someone@someplace.com"))
{
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName =
                                 "someone@someplace.com",
                              Email = "someone@someplace.com",
                              EmailConfirmed = true };
    manager.Create(user, "password");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the user with the findbyName/findById and then updating the user with UserManager.Update()?

Comment: Can the password be updated this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify directly from the DbContext. You don't need to call Identity Library. This is an example.

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Linq;

 public class NameDbContextSeedData : 
 DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NameDbContext>
 {
    protected override void Seed(NameDbContext context)
    {
        var user = context.Users.Single(c => c.UserName ==
        "someone@someplace.com");

        user.UserName = "someone@someplace.com";
        user.Email = "someone@someplace.com";
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;` this is superfluous as the entity is already being tracked by the `DbContext`. Also, in IF6, `context.Commit();` is not a method on the `DbContext` as far as I am aware. Finally you can replace `Where` with `Single` keeping the lambda the same and remove the `Single` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, i made the changes.